# Is there a way to monitor Hadoop metrics using Prometheus?

Tags: hadoop, prometheus, jmx

So I am currently running dual clusters for data processing, one is a Kubernetes clusters and another is a Hadoop cluster.

K8s cluster is taken care of in terms of monitoring since it was quite easy to deploy Prometheus and Grafana on it.

For the **Hadoop cluster** however, I am still looking of a good way to do that.

The goal is to have a unified monitoring solution, so I though it would be a good idea to go with Prometheus since I am already familiar with it, but looks like it's not straight-forward.

Hadoop by default exposes some metrics through HTTP API but those metrics are not "Prometheus-friendly".

Would appreciate if you can explain how I can achieve this.

Comment: What issues have you had with adding this to you Hadoop processes? https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you look at this,
https://github.com/marcelmay/hadoop-hdfs-fsimage-exporter

in most cases when the application does not expose prometheus metrics you can use an exporter there are a lot of them.

they collect the metrics and expose them in a Prometheus friendly manner.

Comment: This is only for the FSImage, not JMX

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution specifically for Hadoop, you would have to use the JMX exporter https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

This is what the official Prometheus docs recommend as well https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

> The JMX exporter can export from a wide variety of JVM-based
> applications, for example Kafka and Cassandra.